# Nvidia Drivers error while rebooting PC

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Installed Ubuntu version 22.04.1 LTS after the first run everything worked perfectly and there were no problems. But after I restarted my PC 2 times, my nvidia-settings disappeared, the nvidia-smi command did not work (Before that, everything worked) And the image started tearing when I watched various videos. I tried installing different drivers but the gaps remained. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the Ubuntu version is 20.04.1?

Comment: My bad 22.04.1 LTS